# Duplicate Devise flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've implemented Devise in Rails and it works great except that flash messages related to Devise display twice.

[duplicate flash messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXJEZ.png)

Here is my flash display code in application in **application.html.erb**:

```
<% if notice %><div class="alert alert-info"><%= notice %></div><% end %>
<% if alert %><div class="alert alert-warning"><%= alert %></div><% end %>

<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
<% end %>
```

Thank you for helping out a new Rails developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code renders the flash message:

```
<% if notice %><div class="alert alert-info"><%= notice %></div><% end %>
<% if alert %><div class="alert alert-warning"><%= alert %></div><% end %>
```

This piece of code also renders the (duplicate) flash message:

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
<% end %>
```

That is why you are seeing it twice.  You should pick one and delete the other.  I recommend keeping the second code segment.

Comment: Thank you. I feel ridiculous now for answering it, but I'm happy that you did.